# I want to encode and decode a UIImage to and from a String for a value in AEXML in swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, uiimage

//To encode I found the following example.  I don't know if it works yet

@IBAction func exitImageViewController(seque:UIStoryboardSegue){

```
    let imageController = seque.destination as! MyImageViewController
    let myView = imageController.imageView
    imageData  = UIImagePNGRepresentation((myView?.image!)!)
    imageString = imageData?.base64EncodedString()
```

// Is this swift code correct?

//I cannot find an example of decoding String back to UIImage

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looks fine. To encode back you can do this:

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: imageString!)

let img = UIImage(data: data!)
```